# FastAPI - Kubernets Liveness fails once a different function runs more than 5 sec

Tags: python, kubernetes, fastapi, livenessprobe

I have a Python application of FastAPI based on Kubernetes.

I have configured the liveness, readiness, and startup probes on Kubernetes to run my 'healthz' endpoint for testing if the application is fine or not.

But if I am running a different heavy function, the healthz is unreachable by the liveness and then the pod crashes.

Here's my main FastAPI code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import utils.logger as custom_log
from src.insights import insights_func



@app.get('/healthz', include_in_schema=False)
async def return_ok_status():
    return JSONResponse(content={"status": "All Good!"}, status_code=200)


@app.get("/daily_checkup")
async def daily_checkup_status():
    log.info("daily_checkup endpoint triggered")
    try:
        insights_func()
        return JSONResponse(content={"status": "No stuck jobs!"}, status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("An error occurred: %s", str(e))
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal Server Error")
```

If I am running the 'daily_checkup' endpoint and the 'insight_func()' is running for more than 5 sec, then the liveness fails, and the pod crashes.

I know that I can increase the liveness timeout in the deployments file but there is a different way?

I don't want to rely on the liveness timeout. I want my 'healthz' endpoint to be reachable at all times and not depend if another function finished running or not.

Comment: Since `insights_func` is blocking in an `async` route, it blocks the event loop (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion)). Simply removing the `async` in `async def daily_checkup_status` should make it run in parallel.

Comment: Oh it was that simple!
Thank you!